# Migrate data from an existing database to a newly created mongodb pod in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have created a mongodb pod in my Minikube local cluster with the following configuration, now I would like to migrate the data of my existing mongodb database(run in AWS EC2 instance) to this database, how can I accomplish this?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: mongo-vol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: mongo-pvc
  containers:
  - image: mongo
    name: container1
    command:
      - "mongod"
      - "--bind_ip"
      - "0.0.0.0"

    ports:
    - containerPort: 27017
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mongo-vol
      mountPath: /data/db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't added a comment because I do not have more than 50 reputation but here is the thing:

- You created a Pod using MongoDB and I see the volumeMount set to /data/db. What is this path? Is this volume a hostPath, NFS, external storage?

The migration itself could be accomplished in two ways:

1. by running a mongodump on your EC2 instance:

```
mongodump -host hostname --port 27017 --out /tmp/mongodb-dump
```

Then a mongorestore on your /data/db path.

- You can manually log in on the pod

```
#copy your dump from host to pod using
kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir

#log on the pod 
kubectl exec mongodb -it /bin/bash

#run restore
mongorestore /tmp/mongodb-dump
```

or

2. You can copy all files/the entire /data from your EC2 instance and dropped on the volumeMount your pod is mounting /data/db.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Both solution work perfectly. The volume is a host path.